# Codeigniter with Smarty causing an error

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I'm using Smarty_parser.php and it works well when when I use the parser by itself or if I run the parser then a view call. For example:

```
public function act() {
    @$this->load->library('smarty_parser');
    $data = array('Someinfo');
    $this->smarty_parser->parse('contentTmpls/act.tpl', $data);
    // Load Footer
    $this->load->view('Templates/footer');
}
```

but not if I do:

```
public function act() {
        @$this->load->library('smarty_parser');
        $this->load->view('Templates/header');
        $data = array('Someinfo');
        $this->smarty_parser->parse('contentTmpls/act.tpl', $data);
        // Load Footer
        $this->load->view('Templates/footer');
    }
```

The header view call seems to disappear and does not output anything. I was wondering if anybody has run into this problem or have seen a fix.

Comment: Why are you doing `@$this->load->library('smarty_parser');` is it throwing an error?

Comment: Yep I'm using 5.3 and I get a warning about a call that is deprecated. Something about using a ref in function call ie: foo(&$data)

Comment: I've narrowed the problem to Smarty_parser.php line: 87 $CI->output->final_output = $template; I think it is overwriting or not including the header view output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is kosher but here's the answer.
I need to switch out a piece of code:
From

```
if ($return == FALSE)
{
    $CI->output->final_output = $template;
}
```

To this

```
if ($return == FALSE)
{
    $CI->output->append_output($template);
}
```

Seems to be working fine. Now I just need to see if anybody is maintaining this code to add the patch.